# Grunt integration with Maven

Tags: node.js, maven, gruntjs, npm

I am getting below error while integrating Grunt with Maven. I have gone through similar questions on stackoverflow and it didn't help me hence I am asking it again. I have a Gruntfile.js and package.json file both at the root level of project. I have also added relevant entries in pom.xml for installing npm , node and grunt. When I run the maven build , it does create 2 folders Node and Node_modules and I can see that grunt_cli and other modules are installed but still I am getting below error.

I am new to Grunt and Node. Please guide, what am I missing here?

**Errors:-**
Error 1 ->Local Npm module "grunt-cli" not found. Is it installed?

Error 2 ->Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.16:grunt (grunt build ) on project my_project: Failed to run task: 'grunt --no-color' failed. (error code 3)

pom.xml

```
   <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
      <groupId> com.github.eirslett</groupId>
      <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin </artifactId>
      <version> 0.0.16 </version>
      <configuration>
       <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/.. </workingDirectory>    
      </configuration>

      <executions>
       <execution>
        <id> install node and npm </id>
        <phase> generate-resources </phase>
        <goals>
         <goal>install-node-and-npm </goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
         <nodeVersion>v0.10.18</nodeVersion>
         <npmVersion>1.3.8 </npmVersion>
        </configuration>
       </execution>

       <execution>
        <id> npm install </id>
        <phase> generate-resources </phase>
        <goals>
         <goal> npm </goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
         <arguments> install </arguments>
        </configuration>
       </execution>

       <execution>
        <id> npm run build </id>
        <goals>
         <goal>npm </goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
         <arguments> run build </arguments>
        </configuration>
       </execution>

       <execution>
        <id>grunt build </id>
        <goals>
         <goal> grunt</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
         <arguments>--no-color</arguments>
        </configuration>
       </execution>
    </executiona>
  </plugin>
 <plugins>
    </build>
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "myProject",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "devDependencies": {
        "grunt": "~0.4.1",
        "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
        "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
        "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.10.0",
        "matchdep": "~0.3.0",
        "grunt-ngmin": "0.0.3",
        "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.7",
        "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
        "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.7.0",
        "grunt-text-replace": "^0.3.11",
        "grunt-usemin": "~2.0.0",
        "mkdirp": "^0.4.1",
        "moment": "^2.6.0",
        "grunt-protractor-runner": "^0.2.4",
        "node-promise": "^0.5.10",
        "xml2js": "^0.4.3",
        "request": "^2.36.0",
        "grunt-cli": "~0.1.11"
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have tried frontend-maven-plugin 1.0 ? You should perhaps add generate-resources phase for all execution items. What Maven's goal are you trying to run ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the following snippet from your pom.xml

```
<execution>
    <id> npm run build </id>
    <goals>
     <goal>npm </goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
     <arguments> run build </arguments>
    </configuration>
 </execution>
```

Default argument of `grunt` goal is `build`.
If you put the argument `--no-color` you should also add the `build` argument.